# Why is the stress tensor contravariant?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

The stress tensor relates the traction $\vec{t}$ (force per area) on a surface with surface normal $\vec{n}$ usually written as (when disregarding co- and contravariance)
$$ t_j = \sigma_{ij} n_i.$$

Usually the stress tensor is described as a **contravariant** tensor. But since both force and surface normal are contravariant tensors (vectors) shouldn't the stress tensor be a mixed tensor of type (1,1) such that when considering covariance and contravariance it should read
$$ t^j = \sigma_{\,i}^j n^i.$$

Comment: Yes, but $g_{ij}= \delta_{ij}$... Indeed, it is *by definition* a mixed $(1,1)$ tensor, but working in Cartesian orthonormal coordinates you cannot see a difference in the use of different representations.

Comment: So then saying that "It can be shown that the stress tensor is a contravariant second order tensor" like wikipedia does is meaningless/wrong because if you are in an orthonormal coordinate system there is no distinction, but if you are not, employing transformation rules for a (2,0) tensor would give the wrong results.

Comment: A $(1,1)$ tensor is, by definition,  a linear map $V \to V$. If the vector space $V$ is equipped with a metric $g$, that metric can be used to construct a vector space  isomorphism $g: V \to V^*$. With this isomorphism and the notion of tensor product you can construct analogous isomorphisms between spaces of tensors with equal number of factors, independently of the type. In particular there is a canonical isomorphism $V\otimes V^* \to V \otimes V$. This isomorphism is the one used to pass from ${\sigma^i}_j$ to $\sigma_{ij}$

Comment: More precisely $\sigma_{jk} = g_{ki}{\sigma^i}_j$. When working in orthonormal frames with respect to $g$, **in components**, the action of the isomorphism is the identity. However there are two (actually four) different, but isomophically equivalent, representations of the stress tensor. The physical definition ${\sigma^i}_j$ and $\sigma^{ij}$, ${\sigma_i}^j$, $\sigma_{ij}$. You can appreciate the difference in components only if dealing with non-orthonormal frames.

Comment: Assuming basic axioms of continuous body mechanics, Cauchy's theorem proves that the map associating a vector  $n$ to the stress $s$ applied to the surface normal to $n$ in a continuous body is **linear**. That is sufficient to prove that there is a tensor $\sigma$ representing that map. By construction  $s^i= {\sigma^i}_jn^j$. Hence physics states that $\sigma \in V \otimes V^*$, namely a tensor of type $(1,1)$.

Comment: All that is consistent with the transformation rules of tensors **if dealing with orthonormal basis**. Everything is based on the fact that if you transform contravariant components with $R$, then covariant components are transformed using $(R^{-1})^t$. However, if the used basis are orthonormal, then $R \in O(3)$ and $(R^{-1})^t = R$. And you cannot notice the difference... ${\sigma^i}_j$ and $\sigma_{ij}$ transform in the same way in orthonormal frames.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer. I think I understand everything you say above (but shouldn't the covariant components transform as $R^{−1}$ rather than $(R^{−1})^t$?. But say that I gave you a stress tensor $σ_{ij}$ with a change of basis matrix $R$ (between non-orthonormal bases) and said $\sigma$ was contravariant. Wouldn't it be easy to assume that it should transform as $\sigma^{kl} = \sigma^{ij} (R)^k_{\,j}(R)^l_{\,i}$ (a 2,0 tensor) rather than the (correct, I think) $\sigma^k_l = \sigma^i_j (R^{-1})^j_{\,k}(R)^l_{\,i}$ (for a 1,1 tensor)

Comment: **covariant components** transform with the transposed inverse. If referring to bases, $e'_i = {A^j}_i e_j$ and $e'^{*k} = {B_h}^k  e^{*h}$ the simultaneous requirements $\langle e_i, e^{*k}\rangle = \delta_i^k$ and $\langle e'_j, e'^{*h}\rangle = \delta_j^h$ imply ${A^j}_i {B_h}^i  = \delta^j_h$. In terms of matrices $AB^t = I$, that is $B= (A^{-1})^t$ as I said.