# What type of tensor is the stress tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus, stress-strain

I am having some problems identifying the what type of tensor the stress tensor is.

Say we have two bases $B = \{\mathbf{e}_i\}$ and $\bar{B} = \{\mathbf{\bar{e}}_i\}$ that are transformed according to $ \mathbf{\bar{e}}_i = F_{ji} \mathbf{e}_j$ and $ \mathbf{{e}}_i = B_{ji} \mathbf{\bar{e}}_j$.

Now the stress tensor $\sigma$ can in the $B$ basis be defined as

$$ \mathbf{f}  = \sigma_{ij} (\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{e}_i)\mathbf{e}_j \tag{1} \label{stress1} $$

Transforming to the $\bar{B}$ basis we get

$$ \begin{align} \mathbf{f}  &= \sigma_{ij} (\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot B_{ki}\mathbf{\bar{e}}_k)B_{lj}\mathbf{\bar{e}}_l \\ 
&= \sigma_{ij} B_{ki} B_{lj} (\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{\bar{e}}_k)\mathbf{\bar{e}}_l \\
&= \bar{\sigma}_{ij} (\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{\bar{e}}_k)\mathbf{\bar{e}}_l
 \end{align}  $$

So $ \bar{\sigma}_{ij} = \sigma_{ij} B_{ki} B_{lj} $. Hence $\sigma$ transforms as a doubly contravariant tensor and is therefore of type (2,0). All well and good.

But rewriting \eqref{stress1} slightly, using only components

$$ f_j = \sigma_{ij} n_i$$

where the components are given in the $B$ basis. Transforming to the $\bar{B}$ basis (using that vector components transform contravariantly),

$$
\begin{align}
F_{jk}\bar{f}_k = \sigma_{ij}F_{il} \bar{n}_l
\end{align}
$$

multiplying by $B_{rj}$

$$
\begin{align}
B_{rj} F_{jk}\bar{f}_k &= B_{rj}\sigma_{ij}F_{il} \bar{n}_l \\
\delta_{rk} \bar{f}_k&= B_{rj}\sigma_{ij}F_{il} \bar{n}_l \\
\bar{f}_r&= B_{rj}\sigma_{ij}F_{il} \bar{n}_l \\
\bar{f}_r&= \bar{\sigma}_{rl} \bar{n}_l
\end{align}
$$

So $\sigma$ transforms as $\bar{\sigma}_{rl} = B_{rj}\sigma_{ij}F_{il}$ which would indicate one component transforms covariantly and the other contravariantely making it a type (1,1)-tensor. Which seems to contradict the previous result. Or does it?

(I have avoided upper and lower indices to not make any premature assumptions on the type of tensors).

(An answer not involving the word *isomorphism* stands a greater chance of being understood. Or an explanation of why it can't be avoided. I have seen several variants of this question here on SE but I think I typically get lost when this word appears...)

Comment: It would be helpful to link to the previous discussions, [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76048/type-valence-of-the-stress-tensor/76053) and [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/693956/why-is-the-stress-tensor-contravariant) in particular. [This Wikipedia talk page exchange may also be useful.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ACauchy_stress_tensor#Tensor_Type)

Comment: Yes, should have linked to those. Thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately none the wiser from the wiki page, except some comfort in that others are also confused...